# How to use named constants in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, constants

I'm trying to use [named constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) in a Symfony2 project which are required by my in-house third-party code. Is there a way of managing such configuration parameters using Symfony2 ymls?

Comment: Can you provide some code to elaborate on your question? Where are you defining the constants?

Comment: @DarraghEnright: The problem is, there is some in-house 3rd party code that uses named constants and now I need to use those libraries in my Symfony 2.8 code, so I need a way to automatically define the constants from Symfony (whether using yml or container etc.)

Comment: maybe interesting? http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html. see 'Miscellaneous Configuration'. I would:  import your `third_party_config.php` file. In there use `define('THIRDPARTY_ACME_ONF1', 'value 1');` etc. ?

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent, this works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the update Batman - haha that's an amusing sentence. @RyanVincent - you should post an answer, that looks like a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, which is part of the official `Symfony 2` documentation which looked interesting:

[How to Set External Parameters in the Service Container](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html).

**The final section in the document is interesting as it describes how you can use the PHP `include` statement to run any PHP script file as part of the application configuration.**

The document:

#### Miscellaneous Configuration

The imports directive can be used to pull in parameters stored elsewhere. Importing a PHP file gives you the flexibility to add whatever is needed in the container. The following imports a file named parameters.php.

```
YAML

# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php }

XML

<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<imports>
    <import resource="parameters.php" />
</imports>

PHP

// app/config/config.php
// $loader->import('parameters.php');

// our third party config
$loader->import('ThirdPartyDefines.php');
```

Now, all that is required is create a script called something like:

`ThirdPartyDefines.php`

In that file have the required defines : i.e.

```
define('THIRD_PARTY_V1', 'ACME_value1');
define('THIRD_PARTY_V2', 'ACME_value12');
```

etc.

Comment: The part about constants in the link you give seems to be the opposite: it’s using a constant to define the value of a parameter in the Dependency Injection Container.

Comment: @Olivier'Ölbaum'Scherler,  Thanks for pointing out that the answer was not as clear as it could be. Updated it.

Comment: Apologies for late discovery but the above answer does not work. Actually whatever is there in parameters.yml is probably only executed once!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) for this :

```
$container->hasParameter('namedConstant');
$container->getParameter('namedConstant');
$container->setParameter('namedConstant', 'a new value');
```

Comment: Interesting.  Are you suggesting that Symfony container parameters end up generating php defines?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: @Cerad : you're right, to be more precise : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#constants-as-parameters

Comment: So given that his third party code probably does not use the Symfony container, how does your answer address the question?

Comment: I think the point is to create a named constant in sf, maybe I missunderstand

Comment: @Cerad: Yes I need such a functionality where container parameters become constants.

Comment: Probably want to override AppKernel::boot then pull the parameters you need from the container and then call define on them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bundle that integrates your in-house code into Symfony. You could use parameters or [the bundle’s configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html) to provide the values that the bundle will then define as constants.

Imagine you generate a bundle, `GreatInHouseProjectBundle`. You will also get an extension, `GreatInHouseProjectBundle\DependencyInjection\GreatInHouseProjectExtension`. You could then define your constants there.

Using a parameter:

```
class GreatInHouseProjectExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        # ...

        if( ! defined('THIRD_PARTY_V1') ) {
            define(
                'THIRD_PARTY_V1',
                $container->getParameter('third_party.version')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Using the bundle configuration:

```
class GreatInHouseProjectExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        if( ! defined('THIRD_PARTY_V1') ) {
            define(
                'THIRD_PARTY_V1',
                $config['third_party_version']
            );
        }
    }
}
```